# using paper-tabs in a component in dart angular2

Tags: angular, dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to utilize polymer paper-tabs in a dart angular2 component, but am unable.  What am I missing in the code below?

In the following code, the paper-tabs specified in the index.html template work fine, but the paper-tabs in the main-app.html are not formatted correctly and disappear when clicked without any proper animation.

*pubspec.yaml*

```
name: tabs_test
version: 0.0.1
description: Test Paper Tabs
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.13.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  angular2: ^2.0.0-beta.13.1
  polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.16
  polymer_elements: ^1.0.0-rc.8
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/index.html
- angular2:
    platform_directives:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_DIRECTIVES'
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#FORM_DIRECTIVES'
    platform_pipes:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_PIPES'
    entry_points: web/main.dart
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tab Test</title>
    <script defer src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main-app></main-app>
    <paper-tabs selected="0"> <!-- THESE WORK -->
      <paper-tab>INDEX ITEM ONE</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab>INDEX ITEM TWO</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab>INDEX ITEM THREE</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>
  </body>
</html>
```

*main.dart*

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:angular2/platform/browser.dart';
import 'package:tabs_test/views/main_app/main_app.dart';

main() async {
  await initPolymer();
  bootstrap(MainApp, []);
}
```

*main_app.dart*

```
import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_tabs.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_tab.dart';

@Component(selector: 'main-app',
    templateUrl: 'main_app.html',
    providers: const[],
    directives: const []
)
class MainApp {
  MainApp() { }
}
```

*main_app.html*

```
<paper-tabs selected="0"> <!-- THESE DO NOT WORK -->
  <paper-tab>MA ITEM ONE</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>MA ITEM TWO</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>MA ITEM THREE</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual when Polymer is used with Angular2 you need to enable full shadow DOM

Add this before other script tags

```
<script src="packages/web_components/webcomponents.js"></script>
<script>
   /* this script must run before Polymer is imported */
   window.Polymer = {
     dom: 'shadow',
     lazyRegister: true
   };
 </script>
```

For more details about this topic see https://dart.academy/dart-angular-2-and-polymer-together/

[**Repo project on GitHub**](https://github.com/bwu-dart-playground/angular2/blob/master/so36720611_paper_tabs/web/index.html#L10)

Comment: Added the above to index.html, paper-tabs works as expected now.

Comment: In case anyone else encounters: I noted however that setting lazyRegister to true caused some problems with neon animation in custom elements.  When used, my animations would not run and I find `my-element: transform-animation not found!` (or other animations used) would appear in the log.  Setting lazyRegister to false (the default) eliminates this.