# Angular2 with Polymer Elements + cross-browser support

Tags: angular, polymer

I am trying to use Angular2 with Polymer Elements (currently paper-tooltip, but hopefully more over time). In general, polymer components seem to work ok.

As suggested in a few places (as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37228712/333150) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36722102/333150)), I have added shadow mode for Polymer to get it to work with Angular2 like this:

```
window.Polymer = {
  dom: 'shadow',
  lazyRegister: true
};
```

This gets it to work in Chrome. However, Firefox does not work (and neither does IE, but I'm less worried about that). The same goes for a few different elements (`paper-tabs`, `paper-menu` etc).
Here's a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/u9hLaEDxsEInRD4KKmmz?p=preview) where you can see the results.

I thought Firefox was supposed to be supporting Polymer elements through polyfills (`webcomponents-lite.js` is included in the plunkr)? What I am missing? Is there a way to fix this or do we simply have to wait for native web component support?

## EDIT:

I was running Firefox 48.0.2 (on Windows 7). I have now upgraded to 50.0, which seems to rectify *some* of the issues. `paper-tabs` and `paper-menu` are now working. However, the tooltip still isn't...
Thanks, @tony19 for the hint on the version. (I though firefox updated automatically...)

## EDIT2:

I have tested this in Windows 10 with FF 50.0 as well. It seems somehow that the very first page load succeeds, but subsequent reloads fail to load / show the tooltip correctly. Sometimes the paper-tabs and paper-menu are broken, too. Not sure what's happening. This behaviour was observed by @tony19 as well.

Thanks for any hints

Ben

Comment: Your plunker works fine for me in Firefox 49 on macOS Sierra. What version is your Firefox?

Comment: @tony19: Thanks for the tip. I thought Firefox would automatically update... see edited response for details.

Comment: Hmm. Tooltip works fine for me in Firefox on macOS :)

Comment: Your plunker's `<paper-tooltip>` also works in Firefox 50 on Windows 10.

Comment: Perhaps you have a browser plugin that's interfering with the tooltip. Try Firefox's "private window" (no plugins included).